# Grails: How to protect gsp views with shiro?

Tags: grails, filter, uri, shiro

I am using shiro to protect my grails application, using the default setup as with

```
grails shiro-quick-start
```

and a custom user. So far, all controller actions are protected, but if I put in the URL to a GSP-File (say, index.gsp), I do not get a login prompt.

The default filter I use is

```
 def filters = {
    all(uri: "/**") {
        before = {      
            accessControl()             
        }
    }       
}
```

but seemingly GSP-Files do not match this URI-Filter. What URI-Filter do I have to use? I am using grails 1.3.7 and shiro plugin 1.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very interesting, but seems to be a grails problem, not a shiro one.

I didn't manage to secure `/object/view.gsp` pages through the filters mechanism - it seems to be based on controller/action and since there is no controller involved...

But I did find another solution. Add the following line to your UrlMappings.groovy file

```
 "/$folder/${view}.gsp"(controller:'auth', action:'login')
```

this will send your .gsp files through a controller.

Comment: Very good idea, thank you very much! But to secure the main "index.gsp" you also have to add "/${view}.gsp"(controller:'auth', action:'login')